# Declare 3d array with blitz++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, blitz++

How can I declare a 3d array(like arrays nested in arrays which are in turn nested in arrays) with blitz++? Say the dimensions are 3,4,5. Also how would I access said array elements? Could you also tell me how to get the size of each dimension of this multi dimensional array? like for c++ vectors there are oneDvec.size(), twoDvec.size() or twoDvec[di].size() etc.

Comment: General Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Thank you for the list. Needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// declare
blitz::Array<double, 3> blitzArray( 3, 4, 5 );
// access
blitzArray(0,0,0) = 1.0001;
```

Comment: Thank you Oo. Could you also tell me how to get the size of each dimension of this multi dimensional array? like for c++ vectors there are oneDvec.size(), twoDvec.size() or twoDvec[di].size() etc.

Comment: Could it be blitzArray.extent(0), blitzArray.extent(1) and blitzArray.extent(2) for 1D, 2D and 3D array size respectively?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is blitzArray.extent(0), blitzArray.extent(1) and blitzArray.extent(2) for 1D, 2D and 3D array size respectively.